# How to implement multithreading in Spring based Application in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-mvc

I have a CacheLoading Module(calls some WebServices in a "for loop" (80-90 Iterations)). I need to implement Multithreading in "for loop" (for calling webservices in a parallel way). How to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the java 5 executors framework and submit async tasks to it, or you can use `@Async` on the method invoked and make it return `Future<YourResultObject>`